# How to add . in @INC in perl in ubuntu desktop 18.0.4

Tags: 18.04, perl

As the title says i'm looking for a way to do so, i'm using ubuntu/linux for the first time and i had already tried environment variables etc but none of them worked for me. So it would be great if someone can guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the `BEGIN` section of your script:

```
push(@INC, ".");
```